# Mysqldump hangs in pod

Tags: kubernetes

I am running in a pod a `mysqldump` as a `cronJob`. The dump is couples of GB heavy. For some reason it always hang when it reaches a certain size depending the node where it is been scheduled
e.g Node A-> 967Mb, Node B-> 18Gb, Node C-> 967Mb
I try to use a PVC to store temporary the data but it does not make any difference

```
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "PersistentVolumeClaim"
metadata:
  name: "mysqldump"
  namespace: "cicd"
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: gp2
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 15Gi
```

Since there is no resource / request such as Disk Space, i am not sure where to look at

Comment: can you share your PVC yaml?

Comment: ```---
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: "PersistentVolumeClaim"
metadata: 
  name: "mysqldump"
  namespace: "cicd"
spec: 
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: gp2
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 15Gi
```